# TextViews are showing unexpected paste option

Tags: android

In an Activity I have some `textviews` which includes `multi-line` and `long-messages`, the `textviews` also have vertical scroll in them, these text views also have `long-click-listener` on them. Now the problem is that when I click on any of the `textviews` it gives me paste option and it also pastes the text on it (if I click paste). I have tried to set `android:editable="false"` but it does not work. So Please help.

**XML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:id="@+id/helpActivityScroll_id">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context="com.example.appdeveloper.appname.HelpActivity">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/helpAppImage_id"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@drawable/app"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/helpAppText_id"
            android:inputType="textLongMessage|textMultiLine"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/helpAppImage_id"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/helpAppImage_id"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/helpAppImage_id"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#ff003b"
            android:layout_below="@+id/helpAppText_id"
            android:id="@+id/helpAppPeopleSeparator_id"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/helpTrustedPeopleImage_id"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@drawable/trusted"
            android:layout_below="@+id/helpAppPeopleSeparator_id"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/helpTrustedPeopleText_id"
            android:inputType="textLongMessage|textMultiLine"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/helpTrustedPeopleImage_id"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/helpTrustedPeopleImage_id"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/helpTrustedPeopleImage_id"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#ff003b"
            android:layout_below="@+id/helpTrustedPeopleText_id"
            android:id="@+id/helpPeopleRingSeparator_id"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/helpRingImage_id"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ring"
            android:layout_below="@+id/helpPeopleRingSeparator_id"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/helpRingText_id"
            android:inputType="textLongMessage|textMultiLine"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/helpRingImage_id"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/helpRingImage_id"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/helpRingImage_id"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#ff003b"
            android:layout_below="@+id/helpRingText_id"
            android:id="@+id/helpRingLocationSeparator_id"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/helpLocationImage_id"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@drawable/location"
            android:layout_below="@+id/helpRingLocationSeparator_id"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/helpLocationText_id"
            android:inputType="textLongMessage|textMultiLine"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/helpLocationImage_id"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/helpLocationImage_id"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/helpLocationImage_id"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#ff003b"
            android:layout_below="@+id/helpLocationText_id"
            android:id="@+id/helpLocationPictureSeparator_id"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/helpPictureImage_id"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@drawable/picture"
            android:layout_below="@+id/helpLocationPictureSeparator_id"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/helpPictureText_id"
            android:inputType="textLongMessage|textMultiLine"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/helpPictureImage_id"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/helpPictureImage_id"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/helpPictureImage_id"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#ff003b"
            android:layout_below="@+id/helpPictureText_id"
            android:id="@+id/helpPictureSimSeparator_id"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:id="@+id/helpSimImage_id"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:src="@drawable/sim"
            android:layout_below="@+id/helpPictureSimSeparator_id"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Text"
            android:id="@+id/helpSimText_id"
            android:inputType="textLongMessage|textMultiLine"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/helpSimImage_id"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/helpSimImage_id"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/helpSimImage_id"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

**JAVA Code:**

```
package com.example.appdeveloper.appname;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class HelpActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnLongClickListener, View.OnTouchListener {

    private ScrollView helpActivityScrollView;
    private TextView helpApp;
    private TextView helpTrustedPeople;
    private TextView helpRing;
    private TextView helpLocation;
    private TextView helpPicture;
    private TextView helpSim;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_help);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ff003b")));
        actionBar.setTitle("Help");

        helpActivityScrollView = ((ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.helpActivityScroll_id));
        helpActivityScrollView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        helpApp = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.helpAppText_id);
        helpApp.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        helpApp.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        helpTrustedPeople = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.helpTrustedPeopleText_id);
        helpTrustedPeople.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        helpTrustedPeople.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        helpRing = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.helpRingText_id);
        helpRing.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        helpRing.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        helpLocation = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.helpLocationText_id);
        helpLocation.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        helpLocation.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        helpPicture = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.helpPictureText_id);
        helpPicture.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        helpPicture.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        helpSim = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.helpSimText_id);
        helpSim.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
        helpSim.setOnLongClickListener(this);

        String appHelp = "log and multi line message 1";
        helpApp.setText(appHelp);

        String trustedPeopleHelp = "log and multi line message 2";
        helpTrustedPeople.setText(trustedPeopleHelp);

        String ringHelp = "log and multi line message 3";
        helpRing.setText(ringHelp);

        String locationHelp = "log and multi line message 4";
        helpLocation.setText(locationHelp);

        String pictureHelp = "log and multi line message 5";
        helpPicture.setText(pictureHelp);

        String simHelp = "log and multi line message 6";
        helpSim.setText(simHelp);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        view.getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        helpActivityScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: This is a wall of (mostly repeated) code, cut it down just to the part that's relevant please ([mcve])

Answer (score 0):

Add empty click listener for it which override default behaviour of textView. same thing you can apply for other textview like below :

```
  helpSim.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

Hope these solve your problem.